# Lambda Calculus Notation

Tags: lambda-calculus, types-and-programming-languages

I'm reading through the paper `Transactors: A Programming Model for Maintaining
Globally Consistent Distributed State in Unreliable
Environments` by John Field and Carlos Varela.

I have basic knowledge about the lambda calculus (typed lambda calculus to be more precise) thanks to a class I took at my university.

However, I'm stuck finding out what the rule shown below actually means. I have looked through the `Types and Programming Languages` book by Benjamin Pierce but I can't seem to find an explanation.

[image]

Could somebody help me understand what rule `pur7` means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably depends on what $\mathcal{F}$ is -- the text tells you.
Each $f\in\mathcal{F}$ is a build-in/primitive function (such as $+$) and [pur7] gives the result of applying it to some arguments. $[\![ f]\!]$ gives the semantic interpretation of the function, and applying that to the arguments $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ gives the result of the function.

Comment: I was just spitting through the text but you beat me to it! It is indeed the case. I should have checked all the definitions. Thank you for clarifying, it is much appreciated!